# Excel IF function "Too many arguments" Fix

Tags: excel

Basically, I put together an IF function in Excel and it's saying I have too many arguments. Previously I had gone over the 64 nesting limit but I lowered the nests down to 63.  Have I simply reached a certain limit or is there an error in my function somewhere that I can fix?

The goal of my function is to come up with a bet amount (sports betting) whenever the D column falls in a certain percentage range and the E column falls in a certain odds range. My function is attached. Thank you

```
=IF(AND(D95>=0.1,D95<0.12)*AND(E95>=-132,E95<=-129),5,
  IF(AND(D95>=0.1,D95<0.12)*AND(E95>=-128,E95<=-125),6,
  IF(AND(D95>=0.1,D95<0.12)*AND(E95>=-124,E95<=-121),7,
  IF(AND(D95>=0.1,D95<0.12)*AND(E95>=-120,E95<=-117),8,
  IF(AND(D95>=0.1,D95<0.12)*AND(E95>=-116,E95<=-113),9,
  IF(AND(D95>=0.1,D95<0.12)*AND(E95>=-112,E95<=-109),10,
  IF(AND(D95>=0.1,D95<0.12)*AND(E95>=-108,E95<=-105),11,
  IF(AND(D95>=0.1,D95<0.12)*AND(E95>=-104,E95<=-101),12,
  IF(AND(D95>=0.1,D95<0.12)*AND(E95>=-100),13,
  IF(AND(D95>=0.12,D95<0.14,E95>=-132,E95<=-129),6,
  IF(AND(D95>=0.12,D95<0.14,E95>=-128,E95<=-125),7,
  IF(AND(D95>=0.12,D95<0.14,E95>=-124,E95<=-121),8,
  IF(AND(D95>=0.12,D95<0.14,E95>=-120,E95<=-117),9,
  IF(AND(D95>=0.12,D95<0.14,E95>=-116,E95<=-113),10,
  IF(AND(D95>=0.12,D95<0.14,E95>=-112,E95<=-109),11,
  IF(AND(D95>=0.12,D95<0.14,E95>=-108,E95<=-105),12,
  IF(AND(D95>=0.12,D95<0.14,E95>=-104,E95<=-101),13,
  IF(AND(D95>=0.12,D95<0.14,E95>=-100),14,
  IF(AND(D95>=0.14,D95<0.16,E95>=-132,E95<=-129),7,
  IF(AND(D95>=0.14,D95<0.16,E95>=-128,E95<=-125),8,
  IF(AND(D95>=0.14,D95<0.16,E95>=-124,E95<=-121),9,
  IF(AND(D95>=0.14,D95<0.16,E95>=-120,E95<=-117),10,
  IF(AND(D95>=0.14,D95<0.16,E95>=-116,E95<=-113),11,
  IF(AND(D95>=0.14,D95<0.16,E95>=-112,E95<=-109),12,
  IF(AND(D95>=0.14,D95<0.16,E95>=-108,E95<=-105),13,
  IF(AND(D95>=0.14,D95<0.16,E95>=-104,E95<=-101),14,
  IF(AND(D95>=0.14,D95<0.16,E95>=-100),15,
  IF(AND(D95>=0.16,D95<0.18,E95>=-132,E95<=-129),8,
  IF(AND(D95>=0.16,D95<0.18,E95>=-128,E95<=-125),9,
  IF(AND(D95>=0.16,D95<0.18,E95>=-124,E95<=-121),10,
  IF(AND(D95>=0.16,D95<0.18,E95>=-120,E95<=-117),11,
  IF(AND(D95>=0.16,D95<0.18,E95>=-116,E95<=-113),12,
  IF(AND(D95>=0.16,D95<0.18,E95>=-112,E95<=-109),13,
  IF(AND(D95>=0.16,D95<0.18,E95>=-108,E95<=-105),14,
  IF(AND(D95>=0.16,D95<0.18,E95>=-104,E95<=-101),15,
  IF(AND(D95>=0.16,D95<0.18,E95>=-100),16,
  IF(AND(D95>=0.18,D95<0.20,E95>=-132,E95<=-129),9,
  IF(AND(D95>=0.18,D95<0.20,E95>=-128,E95<=-125),10,
  IF(AND(D95>=0.18,D95<0.20,E95>=-124,E95<=-121),11,
  IF(AND(D95>=0.18,D95<0.20,E95>=-120,E95<=-117),12,
  IF(AND(D95>=0.18,D95<0.20,E95>=-116,E95<=-113),13,
  IF(AND(D95>=0.18,D95<0.20,E95>=-112,E95<=-109),14,
  IF(AND(D95>=0.18,D95<0.20,E95>=-108,E95<=-105),15,
  IF(AND(D95>=0.18,D95<0.20,E95>=-104,E95<=-101),16,
  IF(AND(D95>=0.18,D95<0.20,E95>=-100),17,
  IF(AND(D95>=0.20,D95<0.22,E95>=-132,E95<=-129),10,
  IF(AND(D95>=0.20,D95<0.22,E95>=-128,E95<=-125),11,
  IF(AND(D95>=0.20,D95<0.22,E95>=-124,E95<=-121),12,
  IF(AND(D95>=0.20,D95<0.22,E95>=-120,E95<=-117),13,
  IF(AND(D95>=0.20,D95<0.22,E95>=-116,E95<=-113),14,
  IF(AND(D95>=0.20,D95<0.22,E95>=-112,E95<=-109),15,
  IF(AND(D95>=0.20,D95<0.22,E95>=-108,E95<=-105),16,
  IF(AND(D95>=0.20,D95<0.22,E95>=-104,E95<=-101),17,
  IF(AND(D95>=0.20,D95<0.22,E95>=-100),18,,
  IF(AND(D95>=0.22,E95>=-132,E95<=-129),11,
  IF(AND(D95>=0.22,E95>=-128,E95<=-125),12,
  IF(AND(D95>=0.22,E95>=-124,E95<=-121),13,
  IF(AND(D95>=0.22,E95>=-120,E95<=-117),14,
  IF(AND(D95>=0.22,E95>=-116,E95<=-113),15,
  IF(AND(D95>=0.22,E95>=-112,E95<=-109),16,
  IF(AND(D95>=0.22,E95>=-108,E95<=-105),17,
  IF(AND(D95>=0.22,E95>=-104,E95<=-101),18,
  IF(AND(D95>=0.22,E95>=-100),19,0,)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
```

Comment: I would put separate if checks on multiple cells like
=IF(AND(D95>=0.1, D95<0.12), 1, 0)
and then merge the result with
=SUM(F95, G95)

That would be more clear and easy to maintain.

Comment: I would be using a vlookup() for all those values as they are repeated so many times.

Answer (score 0):

Basically your formula is way too long, and exceed the amount of readable formula by excell,

you can use

> =CHOOSE()

like below

```
=CHOOSE(MATCH(TRUE, (D95>=0.1)*(D95<0.22)*(E95>=-132)*(E95<=-100), 0),
5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 0)
```

It give the same amount hopefully

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to put your data in two tables and use `FILTER` and `VLOOKUP`:

```
=IFERROR(FILTER($I$1:$I$9,(B2>=$G$1:$G$9)*(B2<=$H$1:$H$9))+VLOOKUP(C2,$K$1:$L$7,2,TRUE),0)
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image: Random Data Table]

**1)** First put all ranges for your 2 variables and the corresponding results to extract in a cell range as shown in the image.
**2)** The formula  `=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(C13,A:A,1),MATCH(D13,1:1,-1)))` has 3 parts:
**a)** Match Function to find the correct row and column for the variables values.
**b)** Address Function to transform the row & column numbers into a cell range.
**c)** Indirect Function to get the content of that cell.

**N.B.** Note that match function use a third parameter (1 means less than , -1 means greater than, 0 for exact match [not needed here]) to capture the first range that satisfy the variable value.